# Weird permissions getting set on directories after rsync

Tags: permissions, mac-osx, rsync, chmod

I've got a drive on a Mac (OSX 10.7.5) that I'm sharing on the LAN. In the system preferences, the share is set so System Administrator has Read & Write access, System Group has Read Only, and Everyone has Read Only.

The files in the shared folder are a mirror of files on a remote computer, which are being copied locally using rsync. The remote computer has permissions set so the world has no access, but I want people to be able to access this local share as Guest, so what I was doing was running a shell script that did the rsync and then followed it with chmod -R a+rX and chmod -R go-w. That basically worked, except that while the rsync was running the directories on the share would temporarily show up as unavailable (due to their source permissions), and then once again become available once I did the chmod commands.

So instead I added the parameters --chmod=a+rX,og-w,u+w --perms to the rsync command, and that's when things got weird.

From my desktop Mac, when I look at the shared directory over the LAN, I can see all the files but none of the subdirectories. If I open a terminal window and cd to the root of the share, it shows me all the subdirectories, but if I try to cd into one it tells me "No such file or directory".

I thought it was a simple permissions thing, but from the machine that is hosting the share, if I log in as the administrator and look at the subdirectory using ls -ld, the output shows drwxr-xr-x admin, which looks like what I would expect.

I read up on ACLs, but ls -d -le shows the same thing as ls -ld, which makes me think there aren't any ACL permissions being set.

What am I missing?